# Load UITableViewCell from xib file in a UITableView in a view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a view (not a view controller) that pop up when I press a button.

In this view, I have a `UIButton` and a `UITableView`. I want to use the `UITableViewCell` I designed in a xib file.

So I created my cell class:

```
class PickerViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var flagImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var codeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    func setCell(myObject: myObject) {
        flagImageView.image = UIImage(named: myObject.code)
        codeLabel.text = myObject.code
        codeLabel.font = myObject.kPickerViewCodeFont
        nameLabel.text = myObject.name
        nameLabel.font = myObject.kPickerViewNameFont
    }
}
```

My xib file:

[image]

Here I didn't set the owner of the xib (I tried with as well), I put the custom class for the `UITableViewCell` and no reuse identifier (I tried with as well).

In the init function of my view (the one containing the table view), I do the following:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "PickerViewCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

And finally I implement the method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! PickerViewCell

    let myObject = myObjects[indexPath.row]
    cell.setCell(myObject)

    return cell
}
```

When I want to show (create) my view, the debugger stop at

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! PickerViewCell
```

and I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x7f9b934d8c70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key codeLabel.'
```

What's wrong?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: If you are not changing the font a lot, it's better not to pass them around too often

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection of `@IBOutlet weak var codeLabel: UILabel!` with IB in `PickerViewCell`. Try to reconnect it.

Comment: I did it few times and just did it again now. Still the same.

Comment: The `nibName: "PickerViewCell"` is right? Try to remove the connect and what error do you get?

Comment: @Nico and you should clean project and build again.

Comment: Yeah the cleaning stuff I try it every time it doesn't make sense (thanks Apple!) but this time it didn't solve my problem... When I put a wrong nib name, I get `Could not load NIB in bundle...``

Comment: Can you post the image with the connections?

Comment: And when I use a wrong cell identifier, I get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: @Nico pretty sure it's about the wrong connection. I got that error sometimes when I rename the var, or delete var ... without change the connection.

Comment: I posted the connections

Comment: @Nico Thank you. Everything seems fine. Did you try to remove everything relate to `codeLabel` in the code?

Comment: If I remove it, I get the error for the next one: `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key flagImageView`. It doesn't make sense... I guess I'll just code my cell directly without a xib

Comment: @Nico. Humh. Don't know what happen here :( .

Comment: Yeah... me neither. Thanks anyway

Comment: You mean `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> PickerViewCell `? Cause then I get an error as it's not the delegate's method anymore